# Replace words in a string based on the rules

Tags: typescript

I have a string like this

```
"Hello {{firstName}}, this is {{senderName}}."
```

The rules

```
rules = {
  firstName: "Alex",
  senderName: "Tracy"
}
```

Expect result

```
"Hello Alex, this is Tracy."
```

I want a generic function to convert any string with the corresponding rules to a new string.

Another example:

```
let array = "Hello {{firstName}} {{lastName}}, this is {{senderName}}."
rules = {
  firstName: "Alex",
  lastName: "James",
  senderName: "Tracy"
}
expectedResult = "Hello Alex James, this is Tracy."
```

Any help wound be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of a [replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) that can be passed to [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
const str = "Hello {{firstName}} {{lastName}}, this is {{senderName}}."
const mapping = {
  firstName: "Alex",
  lastName: "James",
  senderName: "Tracy"
}
const compile = (template, rules) => template.replace(/{{(.+?)}}/g, (match, group) => rules[group]);

const result = compile(str, mapping);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can loop through and replace all variable with value

```
    function resolve_str(rules,str){
      for(let i in rules){
        str = str.replace("{{"+i+"}}", rules[i]);
      }
      return str;
    }

    let array = "Hello {{firstName}} {{lastName}}, this is {{senderName}}."
    rules = {
      firstName: "Alex",
      lastName: "James",
      senderName: "Tracy"
    }

    console.log(resolve_str(rules,array));
```